# Find all triplets in array with sum less than or equal to given sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This was recently asked to a friend in an interview and we do not know of any solution other than the simple O(n<sup>3</sup>) one.

Is there some better algorithm?

The question is to find all triplets in an integer array whose sum is less than or equal to given sum S.

Note: I have seen other such problems on SO with performance O(n<sup>2</sup>log n) but all of them were solving the easier version of this problem like where `arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] = S` or where they were only checking whether one such triplet exists.

My question is to find out all `i,j,k` in `arr[]` such that `arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] <= S`

Comment: Might be relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70840659/find-all-triplets-i-j-k-such-that-ijk-n

Answer (score 5):

From a worst-case asymptotic perspective, there is no better algorithm since the size of the output is potentially O(n<sup>3</sup>).

e.g. Let the array be the numbers 1 through `n`. Let `S = 3n`. Clearly, any subset of three array elements will be less than `S` and there are `(n choose 3) = O(n³)` subsets.

There are a few ways you can speed up non-worst cases though. For example, try sorting the array first. That should give you some hints.

Answer (score 5):

I have an idea, but I'm not sure if it works.

Preprocess (remove elements > `S`) and sort the array first.

Then, after you picking up `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` where `i < j`, you may binary search `S - arr[i] - arr[j]` in the remaining `array[j+1...n]`. Once you binary-searched the index `m`, the `k` could lie between `j+1` and `m`.

I think this may reduce the complexity. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I think this will reduce the complexity to n2.log(n)

Comment: Approach could be improved a little, after sorting and filtering A you will have B array of length n. Then you have to iterate over the elements of array `B[i]` and detect windows `B[j..k]` which are suitable with the next formula:
...
<code>
j = 1;
if (B[i]+B[j] <= S) {
   k = binarySearch(B, B[j] + B[i]);
   loop over j..k and print.
}
</code>

Comment: @user486075 I'm trying my best to understand your word. Do you mean that when `arr[i] + arr[j] > S` holds, we do not need to binary-search for `k` at all?

Comment: you are right, it could be wrong in case of negative numbers.

Comment: @AnnieKim, the improvement is actually next - once you have initial value `i` one can detect window for `k` by binary searching for the `S - a[i] - a[1]`, then all you have to do is to enumerate all pairs from window `1..k`, and this could be done in a single loop - "increase j and decrease k", some corner cases that needs to be handled are when you have same numbers, or k should be used multiple times, or j should be used several times

Comment: +1 for introducing 3 useful steps - reduce the problem (remove >S elements), sorting, and introducing binary-search for the 3rd element.

Comment: No. check @tskuzzy s answer.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the complexity of this?

If applied to a sorted list (ascending), `f` simply lists the triplets who's sum is less than or equal to `s`, one by one, without creating duplicates or scanning past the first element that is too big.

Haskell code:

```
f []     s result = if length result == 3 then [result] else []
f (x:xs) s result
  | length result == 3   = [result]
  | x + sum result > s   = []
  | otherwise            = f xs s (x:result) ++ f xs s result
```

Output:

```
*Main> length $ f [1..300] 300 []
731375
(5.09 secs, 402637784 bytes)

*Main> f [1..10] 13 []
[[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[5,2,1],[6,2,1],[7,2,1],[8,2,1],[9,2,1],[10,2,1],[4,3,1]
,[5,3,1],[6,3,1],[7,3,1],[8,3,1],[9,3,1],[5,4,1],[6,4,1],[7,4,1],[8,4,1]
,[6,5,1],[7,5,1],[4,3,2],[5,3,2],[6,3,2],[7,3,2],[8,3,2],[5,4,2],[6,4,2]
,[7,4,2],[6,5,2],[5,4,3],[6,4,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

First sort the numbers → O(nlog(n))

Now starting from the front, fix one number at a time. Now problem reduces to find 2 numbers in sorted array whose sum is <= given sum. Using 2 pointers, one from start and one from end, this can be solved in O(n). So overall complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Answer (score 0):

**I'm keeping my original answer below, but this can actually be solved in O(n).** My new solution uses a Queue to keep track of the triplets. It only returns the number of triplets but you could create a list to track the triplet lists pretty easily if that is what's required.

```py
    class Queue (object):
      def __init__ (self):
        self.queue = []
        self.itemCount = 0

      def enqueue (self, item):
        self.queue.append (item)
        self.itemCount += 1

      def dequeue (self):
        self.itemCount += 1
        return (self.queue.pop(0))


    def findAllTriplets(li,S):
      if len(li) < 3:
        return "Not enough elements for triplets"
      tQ = Queue() # Queue to keep track of data
      tripletNum = 0 # Integer to track number of triplets to be returned
      tripletSum = 0 # Value of sum of consecutive list items for tripletNum evaluation
      for number in li:
        # Add the number to the queue immediately and add it to the current triplet sum
        tQ.enqueue(number)
        tripletSum += number
        # For the first 3 numbers only enqueue and add to the sum
        if tQ.itemCount < 3:
          continue
        # Afterwards, check if the sum of the latest three is less than S
        else:
          if(tripletSum <= S):
            tripletNum += 1
          # Dequeue the oldest element in the queue and subtract it from the tracked triplet sum
          tripletSum -= tQ.dequeue()
      return tripletNum
```

I believe this algorithm should do the trick in O(N<sup>2</sup>). You should sort the array beforehand though.

Essentially, I am just finding all possible triplets where the first index i is zero and the next index is j by searching through the remaining indices (k) for all sums less than or equal to x (or S in your case). After that, I increment j by 1 and repeat the process. Once j comes to the end of the array, I start the process over with my i being i + 1 now and keep going until i equals the second to last index value (since at that point there are no possible triplets left).

Python code

```py
def numTriplets(a,x):
   if len(a) < 3:
       return None
   i = 0
   j = 1
   triplets = []
   while True:
      for k in range(j+1,len(a)):
         if a[i] + a[j] + a[k] <= x:
            triplets.append([i,j,k])
      j += 1
      if j == len(a) - 1:
         i += 1
         j = i + 1
      if i == len(a) - 2:
         return triplets
```