# Find three elements in a sorted array which sum to a fourth element

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

A friend of mine recently got this interview question, which seems to us to be solvable but not within the asymptotic time bounds that the interviewer thought should be possible. Here is the problem:

> You have an array of `N` integers, `xs`, sorted but possibly non-distinct. Your goal is to find four array indices<sup>(1)</sup> `(a,b,c,d)` such that the following two properties hold:
>
> ```
> xs[a] + xs[b] + xs[c] = xs[d]
>
> a < b < c < d
> ```
>
> The goal is to do this in O(N<sup>2</sup>) time.

First, an O(N<sup>3</sup>log(N)) solution is obvious: for each `(a,b,c)` ordered triple, use binary search to see if an appropriate `d` can be found. Now, how to do better?

One interesting suggestion from the interviewer is to rewrite the first condition as:

```
xs[a] + xs[b] = xs[d] - xs[c]
```

It's not clear what to do after this, but perhaps we could chose some pivot value P, and search for an `(a,b)` pair adding up to P, and a `(d,c)` pair subtracting to it. That search is easy enough to do in O(n) time for a given P, by searching inwards from both ends of the array. However, it seems to me that the problem with this is that there are N<sup>2</sup> such values P, not just N of them, so we haven't actually reduced the problem size at all: we're doing O(N) work, O(N<sup>2</sup>) times.

We found some related problems being discussed online elsewhere: [Find 3 numbers in an array adding to a given sum](https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Find-3-numbers-in-an-array-adding-up-to-a-given-sum-S-QTN_120937.htm) is solvable in N<sup>2</sup> time, but requires that the sum be fixed ahead of time; adapting the same algorithm but iterating through each possible sum leaves us at N<sup>3</sup> as always.

Another related problem seems to be [Find all triplets in array with sum less than or equal to given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17713679/625403), but I'm not sure how much of the stuff there is relevant here: an inequality rather than an equality mixes things up quite a bit, and of course the target is fixed rather than varying.

So, what are we missing? Is the problem impossible after all, given the performance requirements? Or is there a clever algorithm we're unable to spot?

---

(1) Actually the problem as posed is to find all such `(a,b,c,d)` tuples, and return a count of how many there are. But I think even finding a single one of them in the required time constraints is hard enough.

Comment: How about this: Iterate through all the possible pairs and store each sum in a hashmap (key = sum, value = pair). Then do the same but with subtraction in a different hashmap. Then just match keys up and verify the pairs satisfy the inequality.

Comment: Yes I agree with Zar. A hash table or just a lookup table with all pair of sums and substractions.

Comment: I haven't actually tried it, but if you give it a go and it works out I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Zar That seems promising, but of course hash tables do not guarantee O(1) operations. One possible fix is to use an array instead, where the array index is the key (the sum), but then for a small input array with large elements we will end up spending too much time iterating through our lookup table.

Comment: A bigger concern with @Zar 's solution is that what if the indices for sum and difference are common. (s[a] + s[b] = s[b] - s[r]).

Comment: I think using a hash map is still the best option; it's commonly accepted as being O(1), because the probability is very high. Like you said, the array would be too expensive. If the numbers ranged from 1-10000, we would need a huge array.

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal, just keep a list of values instead of a single one.

Comment: @Zar That can possibly blow up the complexity (unless there is a proof otherwise).

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal, worst case is still O(N^2). The bottleneck here is generating all the pairs. Iterating through a hash map of lists would not surpass that. Worst case the list is of size N for one key, but in this case there is only 1 key to iterate through. Still O(N).

Comment: @Zar, After you build the hasmap, you will have to iterate over possibly O(N^2) values of 'sums'. For each such value if you have to carry out list traversal, then it does not remain O(N^2).

Comment: Oh you're right, it is O(N^2) sums. But still wouldn't make a difference. For each list with length > 1 we have one less key to traverse. There is no way to have more than O(N^2) elements to iterate through. O(N^2 + N^2) is still just O(N^2) so we should be good. @Abhishek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the algorithm would have to *list* the solutions (i.e. the sets of **a**, **b**, **c**, and **d** that satisfy the condition), the worst case time complexity is **O(n<sup>4</sup>)**:

#### 1. There can be *O(n<sup>4</sup>)* solutions

The trivial example is an array with only 0 values in it. Then **a**, **b**, **c** and **d** have all the freedom as long as they stay in order. This represents **O(n<sup>4</sup>)** solutions.

But more generally arrays which follow the following pattern have **O(n<sup>4</sup>)** solutions:

```
w, w, w, ... x, x, x, ..., y, y, y, ...  z, z, z, ....
```

With just as many occurrences of each, and:

```
w + x + y = z
```

However, to only produce the *number* of solutions, an algorithm can have a better time complexity.

#### 2. Algorithm

This is a slight variation of the already posted algorithm, which does not involve the **H** factor. It also describes how to handle cases where different configurations lead to the same sums.

- Retrieve all pairs and store them in an array **X**, where each element gets the following information:

  **a**: the smallest index of the two
  **b**: the other index
  **sum**: the value of `xs[a] + xs[b]`
- At the same time also store for each such pair in another array **Y**, the following:

  **c**: the smallest index of the two
  **d**: the other index
  **sum**: the value of `xs[d] - xs[c]`

The above operation has a time complexity of **O(n²)**

- Sort both arrays by their element's **sum** attribute. In case of equal **sum** values, the sort order will be determined as follows: for the **X** array by increasing **b**; for the **Y** array by decreasing **c**. Sorting can be done in <s>O(n²)</s> **O(n²logn)** time.

[**Edit:** I could not prove the earlier claim of **O(n²)** (unless some assumptions are made that allow for a radix/bucket sorting algorithm, which I will not assume). As noted in comments, in general an array with **n²** elements can be sorted in **O(n²logn²)**, which is **O(n²logn)**, but not **O(n²)**]

- Go through both arrays in "tandem" to find pairs of sums that are equal. If that is the case, it needs to be checked that `X[i].b < Y[j].c`. If so it represents a solution. But there could be many of them, and counting those in an acceptable time needs special care.

  Let `m = n(n-1)/2`, i.e. the number of elements in array **X** (which is also the size of array **Y**):

```py
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < m and j < m:
        if X[i].sum < Y[j].sum:
            i = i + 1
        elif X[i].sum > Y[j].sum:
            j = j + 1
        else:
            # We have a solution. Need to count all others that have same sums in X and Y.
            # Find last match in Y and set k as index to it:
            countY = 0
            while k < m and X[i].sum == Y[j].sum and X[i].b < Y[j].c:
                countY = countY + 1
                j = j + 1
            k = j - 1
            # add chunks to `count`:
            while i < m and countY >= 0 and X[i].sum == Y[k].sum:
                while countY >= 0 and X[i].b >= Y[k].c:
                    countY = countY - 1
                    k = k - 1
                count = count + countY
                i = i + 1
```

Note that although there are nested loops, the variable **i** only ever increments, and so does **j**. The variable **k** always decrements in the innermost loop. Although it also gets higher values to start from, it can never address the same **Y** element more than a constant number of times via the **k** index, because while decrementing this index, it stays within the "same sum" range of **Y**.

So this means that this last part of the algorithm runs in **O(m)**, which is **O(n²)**. As my latest edit confirmed that the sorting step is not **O(n²)**, that step determines the overall time-complexity: **O(n²logn)**.

Comment: You say that "Sorting can be easily done in O(n²) time", but can it? You have N^2 items in each list, so call that M. Sorting a list with M items takes `M*log(M)` time, or `N^2*log(N^2)`. This is not a *lot* worse than N^2, but it is not better.

Comment: @amalloy, You are right, I overlooked that. I will go back to the drawing board :-)

Comment: In fact, since the original array is sorted, I think the arrays X and Y can be built to be sorted in *O(n²)* time. I will work on an update of my answer.

Comment: Looking forward to your update to get ordered sums of pairs from one or two ordered collection(s) in O(n²). (I'm still stuck there.)

Comment: @greybeard, I must admit I cannot find an algorithm that performs the sorting step in **O(n²)**, ... It seems the extra **logn** factor is comparable with a conservative measure of **H**, the access time in a hash. I am not going to play the card of radix sort and the like, which would be **O(m)=O(n²)**, as that assumes too much. Too bad :-( Maybe someone else has a bright idea.

Comment: (I went _why, you can generate_ n _ascending sequences; feed them through a priority queue of size_ n _- drat; merge them sequentially - drat, by size…_. Maybe it is useful to consider the extreme case of _n_ ascending sequences of size _1_.)

Comment: Wouldn't either the merging of the priority queues or its conversion to a sorted array add the *log(m)* factor? ([wiki: priority queue running times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Summary_of_running_times))

Comment: And by *Drat* you mean... deterministic rational relationships? Sorry for my ignorance, but I don't know this acronym. Can you explain how you could benefit from this property (I suppose you refer to the already sorted sub arrays) to avoid the *log n* factor?

Comment: ([Drat](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drat) (If it was an acronym, it would rightfully be DRAT, wouldn't it?)(I could only repeat that none of the approaches that came to my mind was without the _log n_ factor, and that the case of _n_ ascending sequences of size _1_ does nothing to motivate me.))

Answer (score 3):

So one solution can be :

List all x[a] + x[b] value possible such that a < b and hash them in this fashion

```
key = (x[a]+x[b]) and value = (a,b).
```

Complexity of this step - O(n^2)

Now List all x[d] - x[c] values possible such that d > c. Also for each x[d] - x[c] search the entry in your hash map by querying. We have a solution if there exists an entry such that c > b for any hit. 
Complexity of this step - O(n^2) * H.

Where H is the search time in your hashmap.

Total complexity - O(n^2)* H. Now H may be O(1). This could done if the range of values in the array is small. Also the choice of hash function would depend on the properties of elements in the array.

Comment: H is O(1) if you check one key.  What is the cost of searching through all the hashmap keys?  It contains all pairs => iterating through is O(n^2)...

Comment: Did not get you, H is time for look up. SO O(n^2) elements are looked up in the map. T = O(n^2)*H. If you use un-ordered map , amortized time for H is O(1).