# How to improve the performance of Leetcode 4sum-ii challenge

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

It is a leet code contest [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum-ii/) which I am trying to attempt after contest is over but my code always exceeds time limit. 
Question is

> Given four lists A, B, C, D of integer values, compute how many tuples
>   (i, j, k, l) there are such that A[i] + B[j] + C[k] + D[l] is zero.
>
> To make problem a bit easier, all A, B, C, D
>   have same length of N where 0 ≤ N ≤ 500.
>   All integers are in the range of -2<sup>28</sup> to 2<sup>28</sup> - 1
>   and the result is guaranteed to be at most 2<sup>31</sup> - 1.

Example:

```
Input:
A = [ 1, 2]
B = [-2,-1]
C = [-1, 2]
D = [ 0, 2]

Output:
2

Explanation:
The two tuples are:
 1. (0, 0, 0, 1) -> A[0] + B[0] + C[0] + D[1] = 1 + (-2) + (-1) + 2 = 0
 2. (1, 1, 0, 0) -> A[1] + B[1] + C[0] + D[0] = 2 + (-1) + (-1) + 0 = 0
```

My code is

```
public static int FourSumCount(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C, int[] D)
    {
        int count = 0;
        List<int> map1 = new List<int>();
        List<int> map2 = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            for (int y = 0; y < B.Length; y++)
            {
                map1.Add(A[i] + B[y]);
                map2.Add(C[i] + D[y]);
            }
        for (int i = 0; i < map2.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map2.Count(); j++)
                //if (map1.Contains(map2[i]*-1))
                //{
                //    var newList = map1.FindAll(s => s.Equals(map2[i] * -1));
                //    count = count + newList.Count();
                //}
                if (map1[i] + map2[j] == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
        }


        return count;
    }
```

is there any better way? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: related: [4sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216582/4sum-implementation-in-java-from-leetcode) equivalent: [Find three elements in a sorted array which sum to a fourth element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39719094/3789665)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest kind of *meet in the middle* algorithm:

```
 A[i] + B[j] + C[k] + D[l] = 0
```

actually means to find out `A[i] + B[j]` and `C[k] + D[l]` such that

```
 (A[i] + B[j]) == (-C[k] - D[l])
```

We can put all possible `A[i] + B[j]` sums into a *dictionary* and then, in the loop over `-C[k] - D[l]`, try to look up in this dictionary. You can implement it like this:

```
  private static int FourSumCount(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C, int[] D) {
    // left part: all A[i] + B[j] combinations
    Dictionary<int, int> left = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    // loop over A[i] + B[j] combinations
    foreach (var a in A)
      foreach (var b in B) {
        int k = a + b;
        int v; 

        if (left.TryGetValue(k, out v))  
          left[k] = v + 1; // we have such a combination (v of them)
        else 
          left.Add(k, 1);  // we don't have such a combination
      }

    int result = 0;

    // loop over -C[k] - D[l] combinations
    foreach (var c in C)
      foreach (var d in D) {
        int v;

        if (left.TryGetValue(-c - d, out v)) 
          result += v;
      } 

    return result;
  }
```

As you can see, we have `O(|A| * |B| + |C| * |D|)` complexity; in case `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` arrays have the approximately equal sizes `N` the complexity is `O(N**2)`.

Comment: Can you please explain this code a little. Actually I have not used such syntax before. Like  if (left.TryGetValue(k, out v)) .

Comment: `TryGetValue` is a popular approach to get Dictionary's value: it returns `false` if no such key has been found; `true` if key has been found and the corresponding value the an out parameter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Dmitry but I have some how made my understanding after some searches over google. I have already visited this link.

Answer (score 5):

Your first step is okay. But use `Dictionary` instead of `List` which will ensure constant time lookup and reduce the complexity of second part.

This was my C++ `O(n^2)` solution:

```
int fourSumCount(vector<int>& A, vector<int>& B, vector<int>& C, vector<int>& D) {
    int n = A.size();
    int result = 0;
    unordered_map<int,int> sumMap1;
    unordered_map<int,int> sumMap2;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            int sum1 = A[i] + B[j];
            int sum2 = C[i] + D[j];
            sumMap1[sum1]++;
            sumMap2[sum2]++;
        }
    }
    for(auto num1 : sumMap1) {
        int number = num1.first;
        if(sumMap2.find(-1 * number) != sumMap2.end()) {
            result += num1.second * sumMap2[-1 * number];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The core observation is - if `W + X + Y + Z = 0` then `W + X = -(Y + Z)`.

Here I used two hash-tables for each of possible sums in both (A, B) and (C, D) find number of occurrences of this sum.

Then, for each `sum(A, B)` we can find if `sum(C, D)` contains complimentary sum which will ensure `sum(A, B) + sum(C, D) = 0`. Add (the number of occurrences of `sum(a, b)`) * (number of occurrences of complimentary `sum(c,d)`) to the result.

Creating `sum(A, B)` and `sum(C, D)` will take `O(n^2)` time. And counting the number of tuples is `O(n^2)` as there are `n^2` sum for each pairs(`A-B`, `C-D`). Other operation like insertion and search on hashtable is amortized `O(1)`. So, the overall time complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: what is int number = num1.first; doing here. other all code is fine but i am unable to understand 
result += num1.second * sumMap2[-1 * number]; and int number = num1.first;
More over what is their replacement in C#.

Comment: @AliMohsin `num1.first` is the `Key` of `Dictionary<Key, Value>` and `num1.second` is the `Value`. Thanks for taking time to understand C++ code :)

Comment: @Kaidul_Islam Thanks for helping and giving me your time. What does this mean ?
sumMap1[sum1]++;
sumMap2[sum2]++;

Comment: `sumMap1[sum1]` here `sumMap1` is the Dictionary, `sum1` is the key and I am storing the frequency of `sum1` - how many times `sum1` exists. After finding `sum1`, I am incrementing the frequency

Comment: Thanks for helping though I was unable to understand whole solution but for your time I am flaging up :) more over if I use 2 nested loops  and after that two nested loops again . Complexity will be N^2 not N^4. Cheers ! Solution of @Dmitry helped me though,