# Find all triplets i,j,k such that i+j+k=n

Tags: python, math, discrete-mathematics

I've coded this but this is very long:

```
for i in range(n + 1):
    for j in range(n + 1):
        for k in range(n + 1):
            if i + j + k == n:
```

Is there a clever way to make it go faster? Currently it's O(n^3) which is quite sad.

Comment: It's easy to get this to `O(n^2)` by selecting `k = n - j - i` and removing the innermost loop.

Comment: Without further constraints, there are O(n^2) possible triplets that sum to `n`, so no, there's not much you can do about the worst-case runtime.

Comment: Question: for i != j, do you need to return both (i, j, k) and (j, i, k) ?

Comment: I think O(n^2) is already pretty great of an improvement

Comment: isn't k going to be negative sometimes though ?

Comment: yes @lukasz wiecek, i would like to return all permutations

Comment: If you allow negative values, then there is an infinite number of triplets (for instance, `(n, j, -j)` is a solution for any value of `j`) so you can't hope to explicitly find them all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few possible solutions - you don't actually need to loop till N in all of them, and the last number comes completely free.

Keep in mind all numbers in triplet must be positive (otherwise the answer is infinite).

1. **If permutations are not included** (i.e. `(1,2,3)` is the same triplet as `(3,2,1)`), going from smallest to largest:

   ```
   def iter_triplets(n):
       # This is the smallest number, can't be more than 1/3 of n
       for i in range(0, n//3 + 1):
           sum_left = n-i
           # This is the second smallest, can't be more than 1/2 of the sum_left or less than the first by definition
           for j in range(i, sum_left//2 + 1):
               yield (i, j, sum_left-j)  # Last number is calculated.


   >>> list(iter_triplets(6))  
   [(0, 0, 6), (0, 1, 5), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 3), (2, 2, 2)]
   >>> list(iter_triplets(10))
   [(0, 0, 10), (0, 1, 9), (0, 2, 8), (0, 3, 7), (0, 4, 6), (0, 5, 5), (1, 1, 8), (1, 2, 7), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (2, 2, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 4), (3, 3, 4)]
   ```
2. **If permutations are not included** (i.e. `(1,2,3)` is the same triplet as `(3,2,1)`), going from largest to smallest:

   ```
   import math
   def iter_triplets(n):
       # This is the biggest number, can't be less than 1/3 of n
       for i in range(n, math.ceil(n/3) - 1, -1):
           sum_left = n-i
           # This is the second biggest number, can't be less than 1/2 of the sum_left and more than first number by definition.
           # ceil to correct rounding errors.
           for j in range(min(sum_left, i), math.ceil((sum_left)/2) - 1, -1):
               yield (i, j, sum_left-j)  # Last number is calculated.


   >>> list(iter_triplets(10))
   [(10, 0, 0), (9, 1, 0), (8, 2, 0), (8, 1, 1), (7, 3, 0), (7, 2, 1), (6, 4, 0), (6, 3, 1), (6, 2, 2), (5, 5, 0), (5, 4, 1), (5, 3, 2), (4, 4, 2), (4, 3, 3)]
   ```
3. **If permutations are included** (i.e. `(1,2,3)` is a **different** triplet than `(3,2,1)`), going from smallest to largest:

   ```
   def iter_triplet_permutations(n):
       for i in range(0, n+1):
           sum_left = n-i
           for j in range(0, sum_left+1):
               yield (i, j, sum_left-j)

   >>> list(iter_triplet_permutations(5)) 
   [(0, 0, 5), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 2), (0, 4, 1), (0, 5, 0), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 0), (2, 0, 3), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 3, 0), (3, 0, 2), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 0), (4, 0, 1), (4, 1, 0), (5, 0, 0)]
   ```

Comment: Yup, that's the correct implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The innermost loop seems redundant since once you have `i` and `j`, `k` comes for free:

```
for i in range(n + 1):
    for j in range(n + 1):
        if i+j <= n:
            print((i, j, n-i-j))
```

If we want triplets of unique numbers that add to `n`, then maybe this could work:

```
for i in range(n + 1):
    for j in range(i, (n - i)//2 + 1):
        out.append((i, j, n-i-j))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to make the code run faster.

1. Use a list comprehension. Syntax [ReturnThing ForLoops Condition]
2. Start each loop from where the previous loop got to. This avoid duplicates

   ```
   def MakeTriplet(n):                                                                          
       return [(i,j,k) for i in range(0,n+1) for j in range(i,n+1) for k in range(j,n+1) if (i+j+k)==n]
   ```

Comment: I  need those duplicates though. That's the thing. (didn't mention it in the question my bad)