# Recursivly looping through vectors with generators in Python

Tags: python, recursion, generator

The following python-code uses recursion to print all lists of nonnegative integers of length 3 whose sum is 2, it works as intended:

> ```
> def rek(f,sum,n,vector=[]): #applies f to all Z^n_+ vectors of sum 'sum'
>     if n==1:
>         f(vector+[sum])
>     else:        
>         for i in range(sum+1):
>             rek(f,sum-i,n-1,vector+[i])
>                    
> rek(print,2,3)
> ```

```
Output: 

 [0, 0, 2]  [0, 1, 1]  [0, 2, 0]  [1, 0, 1]  [1, 1, 0]  [2, 0, 0]
```

My question is if and how I could do this with generators instead? I would like to be able to write something like

> ```
> for vector in vector_generator(2,3):
>     print(vector)
> ```

to print the same vectors.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70840659/find-all-triplets-i-j-k-such-that-ijk-n) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `yield` and `yield from`, here's how you'd do it:

```
def vector_generator(sum, n, vector=()):
    if n == 1:
        yield vector + (sum,)
    else:
        for i in range(sum + 1):
            yield from vector_generator(sum - i, n - 1, vector + (i,))
```

Note that I changed `vector` to a tuple, as giving a mutable object as a default argument is not good practice (editing the value will change the default argument).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your function to a generator in a simple fashion:

```
def vector_generator(sum,n,vector=None):
    vector = vector or []
    if n==1:
        yield vector+[sum]
    else:        
        for i in range(sum+1):
            yield from vector_generator(sum-i,n-1,vector+[i])


for vector in vector_generator(2,3):
    print(vector)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def gen(s,n):
    nums = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    while True:
        if sum(nums) == s:
            yield nums.copy()
        cidx = 0
        nums[cidx] += 1
        while nums[cidx] == s+1:
            nums[cidx] = 0
            cidx += 1
            if cidx == n:
                return
            nums[cidx] += 1
    
                   
for vector in gen(2,3):
    print(vector)
```

Not the most optimal solution but it should give correct results. What it does is basicly iterate over all the possible arrays of length `n` with numbers [0-`s`] and yields the ones that sum to `s`.